# Definite integral of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In evaluating this integration
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\beta x\right) - \arctan\left(x\right)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,,
$$
I separated the $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ term, multiply numerator and denominator with $\beta$ .

$$
\mbox{That gives me}\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(\beta x\right)}{\beta x}\, \beta\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(y\right)}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y\,,
$$
where, $y = \beta x$. It is the negative of $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ term . So, $I = 0$

But my teacher said that I can't do this for this type of trigonometric functions. I can't understand his logic . Have anyone any better explaination ?.

Comment: In short, it's because  $\infty-\infty \neq 0$.

Comment: @JackyChong But where is the error in the substitution ?

Comment: The error came from the fact that $\int (f(x)-g(x))\  \neq \int f(x) -\int g(x)$

Comment: I want to study this type of integrals , can you refer some books?

Comment: Any basic calculus book should do the trick.

Comment: What you should probably do is consider the "partials" - replace $\infty$ with c, and you'll see that the two terms are different.  You have to remember that improper integrals are limits, and so you've got a limit outside the difference.

Answer (score 6):

It can be solved with a direct application of the [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) (assuming $\beta>0$
 ) $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\beta x\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)}{x}dx=\left(\tan^{-1}\left(0\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\infty\right)\right)\log\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\beta\right)}.$$

Comment: (+1) I meant to mention Frullani integrals and got side-tracked.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{\tan^{-1}(\beta x)-\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}(\beta x)-\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}(\beta x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\int_0^{a\beta}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^a\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_a^{a\beta}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_1^\beta\frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\
&=\int_1^\beta\frac{\pi/2}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6}\\[6pt]
&=\log(\beta)\frac\pi2\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write the improper integral as a limit
$(2)$: separate the integrals
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto x/\beta$ in the left-hand integral
$(4)$: combine the integrals
$(5)$: substitute $x\mapsto ax$
$(6)$: dominated convergence, $\tan^{-1}(ax)\le\frac\pi2$, and $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\tan^{-1}(ax)=\frac\pi2$
$(7)$: integrate

Comment: Nice (as usual !). Don't you think that it could be be good to add between $(4)$ and $(5)$ that $\tan^{-1}(x) < \frac \pi 2$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks! How about $(5)$ and $(6)$?

Comment: Perfect. I just thought that it will be clearer to the reader. May I confess that I enjoy the concision and precision of each of your answers ? Cheers.